# RODBC and Access - odbcConnectAccess on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, rodbc

I'm having a similar problem as this one:

[RODBC and Access - Loading data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453974/rodbc-and-access-loading-data)

but I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04 OS.

As stated, I need to query an Access file I have. I've tried

```
db <- "foo.accdb"
con <- odbcConnect(db)
```

which obviously doesn't work as the function I should use is `odbcConnectAccess2007()`, which is not available for package `RODBC` and is not listed on the manual:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/RODBC.pdf

I'm using RStudio Version 0.98.1091 with

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

My question is:

Is there any way I can access an Access database in a file using R from an Ubuntu computer?

Comment: Do you have a compatible driver installed? What does `odbcDataSources()` return?

Comment: The return of `odbcDataSources()` is empty (`named character (0)`, which makes sense as I haven't connected any database yet. As far as I know, which is not much, I have all the drivers installed.

Comment: I think it means that you don't have any drivers installed, at least none that RODBC can see